# Check if an error was thrown when loading an image during page startup

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a JS script that will look through the page when it loads to see if any images had an error loading, and to change the src of that image to a default image. What I was trying to do was to loop through all the list of images returned from `document.images`, and to check every image to see if it finished loading using `image[i].complete`, and if it didn't, then change the src of that image to the default link. It did not work for me, and I can't think of the solution.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var images = document.images;
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (!image[i].complete) {
            images[i].src = 'assets/default-avatar.jpg';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use the `error` event on IMG tags:

```html
<img src="..." onerror="this.src = 'default_image_url';">
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `complete` returns `true` even if the image couldn't be loaded (at least in some browsers), you could use `naturalWidth`. If no image is loaded `naturalWidth` is `0`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var images = document.images;

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (image[i].naturalWidth === 0) {
            images[i].src = 'assets/default-avatar.jpg';
        }
    }
}
```